# HTTP Cookie not being set with Nestjs

Tags: node.js, express, http, cookies, nestjs

I have a GQL mutation called login, which returns a JWT as a cookie in the response.

Although the `Set-Cookie` header is present, nothing appears in my local storage tab. Nothing gets printed in my console either...

Here's my login mutation

```
@Mutation((returns) => AuthenticatedUser)
async login(
  @Context() context: Auth.GqlContext,
  @Args('payload', { type: () => UserLoginDto }) payload: UserLoginDto
): Promise<AuthenticatedUser> {
  const authenticatedUser = await this.authService.login(payload)

  context.res.cookie('jwt', authenticatedUser.jwt, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    sameSite: 'lax',
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31, // one month
    domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.herbievine.com' : undefined 
  })

  return authenticatedUser
}
```

Example response as JSON:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "login": {
      "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjI0N2QyNmY3LTM3NzQtNGRiNS1hM2MzLTE2MTg3Mzk2ODdlMCIsImVtYWlsIjoidmluZWhlcmJpZUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2MzYxMjkyMTksImV4cCI6MTYzODcyMTIxOX0.hHHAAgzs7wFjMP2C565fGGHAd0o-C9h-jA5qzm48OdE",
      "user": {
        "email": "email@gmail.com",
        "name": "Some Name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4000
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjI0N2QyNmY3LTM3NzQtNGRiNS1hM2MzLTE2MTg3Mzk2ODdlMCIsImVtYWlsIjoidmluZWhlcmJpZUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2MzYxMjkyMTksImV4cCI6MTYzODcyMTIxOX0.hHHAAgzs7wFjMP2C565fGGHAd0o-C9h-jA5qzm48OdE; Max-Age=2678400; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 06 Dec 2021 16:06:11 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 319
ETag: W/"13f-MuV4uipvL8ui1YJXuTSvJ1TM1H0"
Date: Fri, 05 Nov 2021 16:06:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

Request:

```
POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:3000/graphql
content-type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Content-Length: 195
Connection: keep-alive
```

For the moment, I still haven't setup my front-end codebase, which will be set to http://localhost:4000. This is all being tested in the GraphQL playground

#### Update

config for gql playground:

```json
{
  "editor.cursorShape": "line",
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Source Code Pro', 'Consolas', 'Inconsolata', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Monaco', monospace",
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "editor.reuseHeaders": true,
  "editor.theme": "dark",
  "general.betaUpdates": false,
  "prettier.printWidth": 80,
  "prettier.tabWidth": 2,
  "prettier.useTabs": false,
  "request.credentials": "omit",
  "schema.disableComments": true,
  "schema.polling.enable": true,
  "schema.polling.endpointFilter": "*localhost*",
  "schema.polling.interval": 2000,
  "tracing.hideTracingResponse": true,
  "queryPlan.hideQueryPlanResponse": true
}
```

App Module:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'schema.gql'),
      context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
      cors: {
        origin:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? '.herbievine.com'
            : 'http://localhost:4000',
        credentials: true,
      }
    }),
    ThrottlerModule.forRoot({
      ttl: 60,
      limit: 20
    }),
    PostsModule,
    CategoriesModule,
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, PrismaService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Auth Module:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: '30d'
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    PrismaService,
    JwtStrategy,
    LocalStrategy,
    AuthService,
    UsersService,
    AuthResolver
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: Where are you making these requests from? Postman? cURL?

Comment: Just in the GQL playground

Comment: What settings do you have in the GQL playground surrounding cookies? Because the cookie is being sent and the browser should be setting  it based on the response  headers you've shown

Comment: I updated the post. Most of my settings are just basic, generic settings. Everything seems to work apart from the setting of cookie

Comment: `"request.credentials": "omit",`, what if this is set to `include`?

Comment: yes thanks! I thought it was something to do with crendentials, but I tried reolving the issue in the response headers, not in the gql pkayground.

Comment: go ahead and add your response as an answer and i'll upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GQL playground by default doesn't send credentials. In the options of the GQL playground, set `request.credentials = 'include'` and it should work

Comment: for me in angular:  { withCredentials: true }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but here is a code example for NestJS users:

```
const GraphQL = GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  playground: {
    settings: {
      "request.credentials": "include", // Otherwise cookies won't be sent
    }
  },
  // ...
});
```